# DataBricks 10.2 pyspark 3.2.0; How Do I Add a New Timestamp Column Based on Another Date and Integer (Hours) Column?

Tags: pyspark, time-series, timestamp, databricks

In DataBricks notebook using pyspark I need to create/add a new timestamp column based on an existing date column while adding hours to it based on an existing hours-bin integer column - this is to support the creation of an event-driven time-series feature set, which requires in this case that the timestamp be limited to date and hour (no minutes, seconds, etc...).  I have tried using string-based `expr()`, `date_add()`, various formatted-string and `cast()` combinations but I get a maddening slew of errors related to column access, parsing issues and the like.  What is the simplest way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion, unix_timestamp is the simplest method:

```py
dfResult = dfSource.withColumn("yourNewTimestampColName",
   (unix_timestamp(col("yourExistingDateCol")) + 
   (col("yourExistingHoursCol")*3600)).cast("timestamp"))
```

Where `yourNewTimestampColName` represents the name of the timestamp column that you want to add, `yourExistingDateCol` represents a date column that must be present with this name within the `dfSource` dataframe and `yourExistingHoursCol` represents an integer-based hour column that must also be present with this name within the `dfSource` dataframe.

The `unix_timestamp()` method adds to the date in seconds, so to add hours multiply `yourExistingHoursCol` by 3,600 seconds, to add minutes multiply by 60, to add days multiply 3,600*24, etc....

Executing `display(dfResult)` should show structure/content of the `dfSource` dataframe with a new column named `yourNewTimestampColName` containing the date/hour combination requested.